# When deploying Django App on Heroku I get the error code H10

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django App on Heroku but I always get the H10 error
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" and at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" and also ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core.wsgi'

this is my Procfile and Debug is turned of

```
web: gunicorn core.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: in your `urls.py` file, make sure that you have a valid `url path` with `/` pattern. Example `path('', views.home, name='home')`

Comment: I think the problem is that gunicorn dose not find the wsgi module I even renamed it to core so it isn't the same as the project